# Authentication with Azure Mobile Services

Tags: c#, azure, uwp

I built a Universal App for windows 10. In my app I'm using Azure mobile services for authentication(Facebook, google, etc.).

```
// Define a member variable for storing the signed-in user. 
private MobileServiceUser user;

// Define a method that performs the authentication process
// using a Facebook sign-in. 
private async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<bool> AuthenticateAsync()
{
    string message;
    bool success = false;
    try
    {
        // Change 'MobileService' to the name of your MobileServiceClient instance.
        // Sign-in using Facebook authentication.
        user = await App.MobileService
            .LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.Facebook);
        message =
            string.Format("You are now signed in - {0}", user.UserId);

        success = true;
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException)
    {
        message = "You must log in. Login Required";
    }

    var dialog = new MessageDialog(message);
    dialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand("OK"));
    await dialog.ShowAsync();
    return success;
}
```

I have a problem with login window. In a low resolution I'm getting  this window.

[Login window in low resolution (screenshot).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hf0Rl.png)

however in a high resolution, I'm getting this window.

[Login window in high resolution (screenshot).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GiYsI.png)

How can I scale this is web page for different resolutions? Maybe I can get access to webview?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't access to the webview because it's OS level, however the big web page still accessible..

Comment: If I have understood you correctly, are you offering use web-browser for logging?

Comment: No, I meant the webview that used by the auth provider